# Must be rational number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $a$, $b$ positive rational number. Suppose that there exist two odd positive integers $p$, $q$ such that $\sqrt[p]{a}+\sqrt[q]{b}$ is rational. Prove that both $\sqrt[p]{a}$ and $\sqrt[q]{b}$ are rational.

Comment: You can find a pretty nice solution to a generalized form here if you have an art of problem solving account : http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/80001

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/93256/23500) to a closely related question.